# how to make a selection from multiple fields?

Tags: python, django

help please make a selection from the fields "nickname" and "family". 
in the database have the following [table](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/tab.jpg). I do sample the field "nickname" as follows: 
views.py:

```
from django.db.models import Q

@login_required 
def friends_search(request):
    search_result = None

    if request.method == 'POST':    
        if request.POST.get('fld_name'):
            try:
                fld_name = request.POST.get('fld_name')
                search_result = UserProfile.objects.filter(Q(nickname__icontains=fld_name))     
                if not search_result:
                    search_result = 'По вашему запросу ничего не найдено.'
            except Exception as exc:
                search_result = 'В данный момент доступ к базе данных невозможен. Попробуйте повторить ваш запрос позже.'   

    t = loader.get_template('friends_search.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'search_result': search_result,
    }, [custom_proc])   
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

the problem is that I need to take a sample at the same time in the fields "nickname", "family". following method does not work:

```
search_result = UserProfile.objects.filter(Q(nickname__icontains=fld_name), Q(family__icontains=fld_name))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revise [Complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) , 
You should use the OR operator | .

It can look like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

@login_required 
def friends_search(request):
    search_result = None

    if request.method == 'POST':    
        if request.POST.get('fld_name'):
            try:
                fld_name = request.POST.get('fld_name')
                q = Q(nickname__icontains=fld_name) | Q(family__icontains=fld_name)
                search_result = UserProfile.objects.filter(q)     
                if not search_result:
                    search_result = 'По вашему запросу ничего не найдено.'
            except Exception as exc:
                search_result = 'В данный момент доступ к базе данных невозможен. Попробуйте повторить ваш запрос позже.'   

    t = loader.get_template('friends_search.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
    'search_result': search_result,
}, [custom_proc])   
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do an AND query, just append filters, like this:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(Q(nickname__icontains=fld_name)).filter(Q(family__icontains=fld_name))
```